# Reading from large file (2GB) and writing to another file using Java concurrency

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

i have a huge file (2GB) which contains employee numbers only. i have to read this file and get the employee number and call database to get the salary of the employee and then write this in another file with employee name and salary as its row.

Now here is the problem, By direct reading this huge file by simple nio in java my STS goes out of memory or it takes 4-5 hrs to complete the entire read-fetch-write process.

So i thought to use the Java concurrency to rescue me.

for that i have a class EmployeeDetails which implements Runnable, in its main method , i have Create a thread pool executor with core size and maximum size as 2,
specify a time out and pass the blocking queue.

```
BlockingQueue workQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue();
In ThreadPoolExecutor along with corePoolSize=2 , maximumPoolSize =20 , keepAliveTime  = Long.MAX_VALUE, workQueue is been passed.
```

then created inputFile File object to getting the input file from path and outputFile Object where i need to write the data.

then i created two object of EmployeeDetails ,

```
EmployeeDetails readFile = new EmployeeDetails(inputFile);
EmployeeDetails writeFile = new EmployeeDetails (outputFile);
```

then `ThreadPoolExecutor. submit(readFile)` and `ThreadPoolExecutor submit (writeFile )` called.

In class `EmployeeDetails` , i have created run method, 
run method open the database connection,
then BufferedReader get the file,
while loop is run untill `br.readLine() !=null`
then for each employee db is called to get the salary as employee are in different shard (MySQL) so as its salary.

once the salary is retrieved i put it in a list and as soon as the list size it 10000. i need to wait a thread and call the wrie thread to write it into file and flush the list to get another 10000 records and thats the problem.

Please suggest a way to read 10000 records from a file , call the db to get details and then populating a list and once he list it 10000 record calling write thread to pic the list and write into another file.

Comment: There's no reason you should run out of memory for such a streaming operation (read-process-write). 2GB is not a big file either, definitely not something that would take 4 hours to process. Show your original code.

Comment: yes , may sound wierd but as there are shards and to get find appropriate shard where the employee details is another problem. and that taking some time. Problem is how can i read and simultaneously write in another file using executor.

Comment: Why is it so slow to find the employee details? I'd be more worried about that, since generally you'd expect finding an employee by its number to be instantaneous.

Comment: There are 64 shards and to find which employee is in which shard takes time. and when its to find records in million the process goes slow.

Comment: Should i go with normal thread concept where i can check if my list reached 10000 records wait my read thread and run  my write thread to write to a file and then once my list is empty again notify mt read thread to start reading the file. or there is some other efficient way using executor

Comment: Doesn't that mean you're using sharding wrong? In any case, if you decide to *try* to speed it up with multithreading, it's the basic producer-consumer problem.

Comment: So what exactly you are suggesting ?

Comment: Well it sounds like your bottleneck is the employee fetch, so you might not get any significant difference. But it won't take too much time to test it out. You are familiar with the producer-consumer pattern, aren't you?

Comment: yes i do , that's why i thought of using Blocking Queue for rescue. But i am stuck how to pass the list to writer Thread once i call wait() at producer which is filling my BlockingQueue.

Comment: There's no need to `wait()`. If you have 2 queues and 3 threads, you'll just need to size the first one to be "suitably" big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it gives significant performance boost to just split reading and writing of the files.

Rather consider splitting the actual work - fetching from db - into threads.

Create `ExecutorService` at the beginning and from original thread just read the lines one by one and wrapped into Callable doing the fetch pass them to executor service. Pass the resulting Future into `LinkedBlockingQueue` which will be consumed by writer thread. That will wait for incoming futures and write the results (this is to keep the order, otherwise you could write directly from the Callable).